# C# / WPF: InvokeCommand not firing on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

As a little background for the question: I have a Model (someProperty), a View, and a ViewModel with the logic. In my View, I have `this.DataContext = new ViewModel()`. Bindings and all that good stuff work perfectly. Interaction triggers and commands work perfectly for buttons and whatnot as well -- the issue I'm running into is described below:

I have a data grid with an InvokeCommand behavior:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="someGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource someSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="someColumn" Binding="{Binding someProperty}" Header="someHeader" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateSomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

The issue that I'm running into is that the command doesn't fire. I (think) know the cause: This trigger is trying to fire the "UpdateSomeProperty" command from the datagrid's datacontext (someSource), but the "UpdateSomeProperty" command is located in the datacontext of the Window, as I said before: `this.DataContext = new ViewModel()`.

You'll notice that I tried using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}`, but I didn't have any luck getting it to work.

Any ideas? I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Where is UpdateSomeProperty defined? Show the ViewModel.

Comment: UpdateSomeProperty is defined in the ViewModel -- it's configured properly. It works fine for commanding using the same syntax for everything else, just not for InvokeCommand behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateSomeProperty, 
                      RelativeSource={
                          RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: I added a `<FrameworkElement x:Key="modelContext"/>` and hooked it up on the backend like my other resources. No luck. :(

Comment: @Shaku: Jason is right (after my edit :)), your binding is trying to invoke something on the Window that doesn't exist.  That's why you have to go through the DataContext first, which is your VM.  What you replied above doesn't make any sense as a reply...

Comment: Okay -- after fiddling with code-to-xaml references and hooking things up in a separate project for testing, I finally got it working. Thanks guys :)